# Paypal ipn - shipment tracking information

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a paypal ipn page that works great, but I would like to store the shipping tracking information for every individual order. The ipn manual doesn't show any variable for that, and I was wondering if I could find a work-around.

So far all I can think of is: Using php to read the confirmation email from paypal and storing the tracking number from there. But I'm imagining that there could be an easier way.

Comment: Unfortunately, IPN does not return tracking info, and you also cannot obtain it via the GetTransactionDetails API.  I've been begging for this functionality since 2009.  Obviously, haven't had any luck getting it to happen.

Comment: Maybe they'll respond to us spamming them constantly? :P

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with getting the tracking information?

Comment: Nope. PayPal is behind on making meaningful changes to their IPN it seems